# Entity framework use already selected value saved in new variable later in select sentance

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I wrote some entity framework select:

```
var query = context.MyTable
   .Select(a => new
   {
      count = a.OtherTable.Where(b => b.id == id).Sum(c => c.value),
      total = a.OtherTable2.Where(d => d.id == id) * count ...
   });
```

I have always select total:

```
var query = context.MyTable
   .Select(a => new
   {
      count = a.OtherTable.Where(b => b.id == id).Sum(c => c.value),
      total = a.OtherTable2.Where(d => d.id == id) * a.OtherTable.Where(b => b.id == id).Sum(c => c.value)
   });
```

Is it possible to select it like in my first example, because I have already retrieved the value (and how to do that) or should I select it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible approach is to use two successive selects:

```
var query = context.MyTable
   .Select(a => new
   {
      count = a.OtherTable.Where(b => b.id == id).Sum(c => c.value),
      total = a.OtherTable2.Where(d => d.id == id)
   })
   .Select(x => new 
   {
      count = x.count,
      total = x.total * x.count
   };
```

Comment: I think also performance here is good. Because second select selects from result of first and not from database... Good thinking ... maybe this is the right approach for me, I will wait a while about other suggestions and that mark the right one (that I use)

Answer (score 0):

You would simple do

```
var listFromDatabase = context.MyTable;

var query1 = listFromDatabase.Select(a => // do something );
var query2 = listFromDatabase.Select(a => // do something );
```

Although to be fair, `Select` requires you to return some information, and you aren't, you're somewhere getting `count` & `total` and setting their values. If you want to do that, i would advise:

```
var listFromDatabase = context.MyTable.ToList();

listFromDatabase.ForEach(x =>
{
     count = do_some_counting;
     total = do_some_totalling;
});
```

Note, the `ToList()` function stops it from being `IQueryable` and transforms it to a solid list, also the `List` object allows the `Linq` `ForEach`.

If you're going to do complex stuff inside the `Select` I would always do:

```
context.MyTable.AsEnumerable()
```

Because that way you're not trying to still `Query` from the database.

So to recap: for the top part, my point is get all the table contents into variables, use `ToList()` to get actual results (do a workload). Second if trying to do it from a straight `Query` use `AsEnumerable` to allow more complex functions to be used inside the `Select`